# How to filter pair of braces

Tags: awk, grep

I have a `.toc` (table of contents file) from my `.tex`  document.

It contains a lot of lines and some of them have the form

```
\contentsline {part}{Some title here\hfil }{5}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Person name here}{5}
```

I know how to `grep` for `part` and for `chapter`. But I'd like to filter for those lines and have the output in a `csv` file like this:

```
{Some title here},{Person name here},{5}
```

or with no braces

```
Some title here,Person name here,5
```

**1.** For sure the number (page number) in the last pair `{}` is the same for both two lines, so we can filter only the second one.

**2.** Note that some empty pair `{}` could happens or also could contain another pair `{}`. For example, it could be

```
\contentsline {part}{Title with math $\frac{a}{b}$\hfil }{15}
```

which should be filtered as

```
Title with math $\frac{a}{b}$
```

**edit 1:** I was able to obtain the numbers without braces at end of line using

```
grep '{part}' file.toc | awk -F '[{}]' '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

**edit 2:** I was able to filter the `chapter` lines and remove the garbage with

```
grep '{chapter}' file.toc | sed 's/\\numberline//' | sed 's/\\contentsline//' | sed 's/{chapter}//' | sed 's/{}//' | sed 's/^ {/{/'
```

and the output without blank spaces was

```
    {Person name here}{5}
```

**edit 3:** I was able to filter for `part` and clean the output with

```
    \contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Person name here}{5}
```

which returns

```
{Title with math $\frac{a}{b}$}{15}
```

Comment: This is extremely confusing.  The first example proposes a GROUP BY operation on the page numbers, but all edits only talk about grepping braces.  Are you after a group by by page numbers?

Comment: @grochmal, thanks for attention and sorry for confusing. I'd like to find the lines containing `part` and `chapter` and then filter the data to collect the names and page numbers so that the final `csv` file looks like `{Some title here},{Person name here},{5}` (with comma and with/without braces). I don't know how to put all 3 info together on a single line of a `csv`  file.

Comment: Does it have to be `awk`? I'd probably use the `Text::Balanced` perl module as that has a `extract_bracketed` call, or there might be other modules that know how to parse TeX.

Comment: OK, my knowledge of latex is enough to understand that a `part` has several `chapter`s but there is one thing that bugs me.  What does the `{5}` do at the end?  Is it always a 5?  I always saw `\contentsline{chapter}{title}{}`, i.e. that last argument was always empty.

Comment: @grochmal, that number means the page number when the `part` begins. You are right when you say that a `part` (could) contain(s) a lot of chapters. In my case, it contains only one. So just after a `part` line below comes a `chapter` line.

Comment: @thrig, I'm trying the most simple command because my knowledge is almost nothing. I tried with `awk` because I remembered it more or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using GNU `awk`, using POSIX `awk` would be very troublesome (lack of `gensub`, which I use more than once).

```
#!/usr/bin/env gawk

function join(array, result, i)
{
    result = array[0];
    end = length(array) - 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= end; i++)
        result = result "," array[i];
    return result;
}
function push(arr, elem)
{
    arr[length(arr)] = elem;
}

# split("", arr) is a horribly unreadable way to clear an array
BEGIN { split("", arr); }

/{part}|{chapter}/ {
    l = gensub(".*{(.+)}{(.+)}{([0-9]+)}$", "\\1,\\3,\\2", "g");
    if ("part" == substr(l, 0, 4)) {
        if (length(arr) > 0) { print join(arr); }
        split("", arr);
        push(arr, gensub("^(.*),(.*),(.*)$", "\\2,\\3","g", l));
    } else {
        push(arr, gensub("^(.*),(.*),(.*)$", "\\3","g", l));
    }
}

END { print join(arr); }
```

This uses the fact that regexes are greedy, so the matches will get the full line each time.  It took more effort than I though at first.

With the following input:

```
\contentsline {part}{Some title here\hfil }{5}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Person name here}{5}
blah blah
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Person name here}{5}
blah blah
blah blah
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Person name here}{5}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Person name here}{5}
blah blah
blah blah
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Person name here}{5}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Person name here}{5}
\contentsline {part}{Some title here\hfil }{7}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Person name here}{7}
blah blah
blah blah
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Person name here}{7}
blah blah
\contentsline {part}{Some title here\hfil }{9}
blah blah
blah blah
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Person name here}{9}
```

We produce with `cat input | awk -f the_above_script.awk`:

```
5,Some title here\hfil ,\numberline {}Person name here,\numberline {}Person name here,\numberline {}Person name here,\numberline {}Person name here,\numberline {}Person name here,\numberline {}Person name here
7,Some title here\hfil ,\numberline {}Person name here,\numberline {}Person name here
9,Some title here\hfil ,\numberline {}Person name here
```

The page number is taken from the `{part}` then any `{chapter}` that happens after the `{part}` is included.  This allows for several chapters inside parts of a book.

Comment: OK, thanks. Some comments: **1.** since I don't have more than 1 `chapter` after `part`, the output should have only 3 blocks, with 2 commas. **2.** How to delete the last comma at end of line? **3.** What do you recommend to clean the lines, I mean, remove `\hfil ` and `\numberline {}` and so on. Could I use after your script some `sed`?

Comment: @Sigur - Last comma?  As of `sed` just remember that this is *nix, add another pipe at the end and place `sed` to kill latex parts `sed -e 's/\\[^ ]\+//g' -e 's/{.*}//g'` should work for ~90% of latex stuff, but to make 100% you would need to use a latex parser (which would involve writing a lot of code).

Comment: Hum, something is strange because now I observed that your output does not contain a comma at end of line. When I run you code on my `toc` file the output is like `5,A Title\hfil ,\numberline {}Person Name,` Observe the ending `,`.

Comment: @Sigur - oops, forgot a `-1`.  It was in my test command line, but not here (edited)

Comment: I found this: `sed 's/,$//'` to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

With the Perl `Text::Balanced` module the top-level `{}` can have their contents extracted thusly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Balanced qw(extract_bracketed);

# this will of course fail if the input is one multiple lines, as this
# is only a line-by-line parser of standard input or the filenames
# passed to this script
while ( my $line = readline ) {
    if ( $line =~ m/\\contentsline / ) {
        my @parts = extract_contents($line);
        # emit as CSV (though ideally instead use Text::CSV module)
        print join( ",", @parts ), "\n";
    } else {
        #print "NO MATCH ON $line";
    }
}

sub extract_contents {
    my $line = shift;
    my @parts;
    # while we can get a {} bit out of the input line, anywhere in the
    # input line
    while ( my $part = extract_bracketed( $line, '{}', qr/[^{]*/ ) ) {
        # trim off the delimiters
        $part = substr $part, 1, length($part) - 2;
        push @parts, $part;
    }
    return @parts;
}
```

With some input:

```
% < input 
not content line
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Person name here}{5}
\contentsline {part}{Title with math $\frac{a}{b}$\hfil }{15}
also not content line
% perl parser input
chapter,\numberline {}Person name here,5
part,Title with math $\frac{a}{b}$\hfil ,15
%
```

Comment: Thanks for effort. I have no idea about your code. The last code block shows the output, right? If so, the output is not what I wish. I'd like something like `{Some title here},{Person name here},{5}` where the 1st brace comes from `part` line and the 2nd and 3rd braces come from the `chapter` line.

Answer (score 1):

In [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr)

```
@(repeat)
\contentsline {part}{@title\hfil }{@page}
@  (trailer)
@  (skip)
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}@author}{@page}
@  (do (put-line `@title,@author,@page`))
@(end)
```

Sample data:

```
\lorem{ipsum}
\contentsline {part}{The Art of The Meringue\hfil }{5}
a
b
c
j
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Doug LeMonjello}{5}


\contentsline {part}{Parachuting Primer\hfil }{16}

\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Hugo Phirst}{16}

\contentsline {part}{Making Sense of $\frac{a}{b}$\hfil }{19}

\contentsline {part}{War and Peace\hfil }{27}

\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}D. Vide}{19}

\contentsline {part}{War and Peace\hfil }{19}
```

Run:

```
$ txr title-auth.txr data
The Art of The Meringue,Doug LeMonjello,5
Parachuting Primer,Hugo Phirst,16
Making Sense of $\frac{a}{b}$,D. Vide,19
```

Notes:

- Because [`@(trailer)`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-01476441) is used, the lines which give the author do not have to strictly follow their part. The data could introduce several `\contentsline {part}` elements which are then followed by the `chapter` lines that match on page number.
- [`@(skip)`](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-021FCB7C) implies a search through the entire remaining data. The performance can be improved by limiting the range by adding a numeric argument. If it can be assumed that a matching `{chapter}` is always found within 50 lines after `{part}`, we can use `@(skip 50)`.

Comment: Interesting. Let me study your code. Thanks.